# android widgets and persistent data

Tags: java, android, android-widget, widget, android-appwidget

I have a litte `appwidget` with a `configuration activity`.
In the `configuration activity` I have a `EditText`
to store a particular string and a button to create the widget.
In the widget itself there is only a `Imageview` with a static image showing a button.

when i press the button im doing the following:

```
AppWidgetManager app_widget_manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
RemoteViews local = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
app_widget_manager.updateAppWidget(widget_id, local);

Intent create = new Intent(this, MyWidget.class);
create.setAction("com.test.mywidget.CREATE");
create.putExtra("toastmessage", edittext1.getText().toString);
context.sendBroadcast(create);

Intent result_value = new Intent();
result_value.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widget_id);
setResult(RESULT_OK, result_value);
finish();
```

the extra `'toastmessage'` is just the content of the edittext.

in the widget i catch the broadcast in `onReceive()` and get the string value that was
passed before as extra `'toastmessage'` to the new widget.

if i press on my widget, i create a toast with the passed string
**- and here is my problem -**
the passed string is different for every widget created.
but the variable (in the widget) where i **store the passed string**
gets **resettet** after a little time or when the phone gets restartet or the app killed or something similar,
so i need **persistent data** for **every widget** instance.

I need to **store** which widget got which string passed,
and **get this data** everytime when the **widget gets updated**.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According with [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) you have some options to accomplish your goal.

- For shared preferences, [here an example.](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/)
- For internal storage [Take this way.](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-internal-storage-example)
- For external storage, [you can use this.](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12437/14-saving-data-to-external-storage-example-android-tutorials/)
- For SQL Lite storage, [here.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Hope these examples helps, cheers.

Comment: but how can i distinguish between the widget instances then?

Comment: hmm i used the shared preferences now, but doesn't work like a charm... but thanks anyway

Comment: You can open other question with your code and errors, me and more people here could help you ;-)

Comment: Actually the question is quite clear, the issue is not only about persisting data, but persist data for each specific widget instance. I don't think it requires a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The `widget_id` you received is a unique identifier of the widget instance. Use it as a key to identify your persisted data.